# import tensorflow with python 2.7.6

Tags: python, tensorflow

Python terminal getting abort with following msg:

/grid/common//pkgs/python/v2.7.6/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 17 2014, 04:05:53)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       2018-02-20 01:40:11.268134: F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:36] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use FMA instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.
> > >       Abort

Comment: How did you install tensorflow? Using default pip distribution or using a downloaded `.whl` file?

Comment: You may have to compile it by yourself.

Comment: I compiled it by myself. 
Can we pass any option during compilation to make it work on all the computers?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer seems to be incompatible with the library tensorflow.

Your computer needs to be able to use FMA instructions but can't.

Comment: Is there any workaround for that like I see on few thread to use:

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'

But this one is also not working

Comment: Maybe use a virtual machine to use it.

Comment: Can we pass  any option during compilation to make it work on all the computers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile `TensorFlow` on the same computer.

Comment: Can we pass  any option during compilation to make it work on all the computers?